# How do I get my characters to heal automatically?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

I've apparently just unlocked "Gambits", which I have enabled for both members of my party.

Both members are currently able to cast Cure, but neither of them (even the one I'm not controlling) are willing to do it automatically. They just attack and I have to vigilantly watch to see when HP might be getting a little too low.

In the tutorial area, however, the AI pretty regularly healed me.

How can I get my party members to actually make use of all their skills instead of just attacking? I've looked through the party menu as well as the overworld menu but haven't seen anything like this.

Comment: Do your characters have multiple gambits set up, or is it just cure?

Comment: @Wondercricket I don't even understand your question. There doesn't appear to be an option to "set up" gambits; all I can do is enable/disable them from the overworld menu.

Comment: I apologize for the confusing question. When I played XII, it took me a while to understand the gambits. Can you provide a screen shoot? It'll be easier to determine with one

Comment: Unfortunately my copy is still in my mailbox, so I haven't been able to experiment with the game to see if the gambits are different. In the original, you would have to set Cure to be cast at a certain percentage of health, and then move it above all combat actions. Then it would take priority over attacking.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The gambits appear to be the same set up

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Disclaimer: this information and explanation is based off from the original PS2 release. I am not aware of any changes that may have been made in the PS2 International Version (with the Zodiac Job System) or the PS4 Re-release*

Your characters can Auto-heal by setting up your Gambits found in the main menu under Licenses

[image: Main Menu]

To set up the Auto-heal, you first you need to buy the Blue Ally Gambits from a store. Examples of such gambits are shown below:

[image: Gambits]

`Ally: [CHARACTER]` are initially available. In the Initial Release on the PS2 other `Ally:` variants become available for purchase, at the earliest after getting trapped in the Nalbina Dungeons. the ones shown in the image however are available after escaping from Barheim Passage. [on the Wikia page](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gambits#List_of_gambits) it says however

> In the Zodiac versions, all gambits are available for purchase after the player gets trapped in the Nalbina Dungeons.

In the example above, Penelo will cast Cure on an Ally whose HP is Less than 70%. You'll also notice the other two Gambits above it. While there are `Ally: Poison` and `Ally: KO` Gambits, there is a hidden [non redundancy system](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gambits#Action:_No_redundant_actions)

> Gambits contain certain hidden conditions to be intuitive and functional. Enemies immediately cease to be targets once they die, and the gambit mechanism will not revive a character who is not KO'd or recast a status buffer if the character still has it

As such, Phoenix Downs and MP for Poison will not be wasted by being used on allies who do not need it.

Gambits execute from the top down. When it is a player's turn, the first Gambit is evaluated and if its condition is true, then it will be executed for that turn and if not, the next gambit is evaluated, and so on. It is for this reason that if you want an ally to Heal instead of attack, as in the example shown above, your attacking Gambits need to be placed below your healing ones, otherwise if `Foe: nearest visible` is at the top, then during combat, it's very unlikely they will execute any other Gambit, as `Foe: nearest visible` is generally always true when in combat.

Finally, the Gambits need to be turned on (symbolized by the G icon) either by pressing X on the ON/OFF option next to the character's name in the Gambits Menu or by turning them on/off in the Combat Menu.

[image: Combat Menu]

Individual Gambits can be turned on and off by pressing X on their individual ON/OFF options

Comment: From the [Gamits Wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gambits), it'll be good to mention that *In the Zodiac versions, all gambits are available for purchase after the player gets trapped in the Nalbina Dungeons*

Comment: Oh I have to buy them? Would be nice if the game mentioned that. If I don't have any, I guess the menu option doesn't appear yet?

Comment: @Wondercricket yeh i didn't read that part and i did recall on the PS2 gambits becoming available after story progression. i'll edit it in

Comment: @Beedrill there are some basic Gambits which should be initially available so once you've been though the tutorial the menu item should appear. also it's been a long time since i plaued it but if i recall correctly i think Balthier mentioned they need to be brought

Comment: I just unlocked the ability to customize them since asking this question. The confusion came because you can "enable" gambits well before you can customize them.

Comment: @Beedrill yeh it's been too long as i don't recall when you get party members before Balthier and Fran and the character i controlled i'd never turned Gambits on, only on my allies.

Comment: @Vemonus sorry about undoing your edit from before. i must have been in the middle of mine while adding the info Wondercricket mentioned

Comment: @Memor-X yeah, our edits were a minute apart, so I suspect that's what happened. No worries

Comment: @Memor-X 2006 was a long time ago ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Order of gambits matter

Think of [gambits](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gambits) as "Order of Operation" whenever the character is about to make a move

> Gambits are a targeted "if A, then X" conditional statement/expression; each gambit on the list is evaluated and the first gambit that has a true, actionable condition, will be executed. Each time the character gets a new turn the list is reevaluated, starting with the first gambit.
>
> **Functionality**
>
> Gambits are composed of a target, a condition and an action to be performed on the target, only if the condition is true. If the condition is not true, the next gambit in the list is checked, and so on
>
> ...
>
> There are several gambits in the game. **Initially, the party starts with very few gambits to work with, but as the game progresses, the party can find or buy more.**

Lets look at this type of examples of

> 1. Ally: 70% < HP => Cure
> 2. Foe: Party Leader's Target => Attack

and

> 1. Foe: Party Leader's Target => Attack
> 2. Ally: 70% < HP => Cure

These two gambit setups look very similar, but the order is very important.

Example 1: Every turn it will evaluate any ally whose HP is less than 70%, heal the ally, and continue this until the condition is no longer met. Once the condition is not true, it goes onto the second gambit of attacking the nearest enemy.

Example 2: Every turn it will locate the nearest target in range and attack the enemy. Every turn, it evaluates the gambits, with attacking the nearest target first. Once this condition is no longer true, meaning all enemies have been killed, then it goes onto healing your allies with <70% HP

Comment: You beat me to it! Very well explained :)

Comment: Where do I even go to set this up though? There is no option for it. Have I maybe not progressed far enough in the story? The game specifically mentioned that they're available though.

Comment: @Beedrill Memor-X provides a much better explanation